# How to kill a stale process

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, kill, pid

I run transcoding on Ubuntu server and sometimes the process goes stale and provides no output but `ps aux` shows process is still running - but with stale CPU usage

I can get the CPU usage with the following command(ffmpeg process i was working with has process id 4416:

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep 4416 | awk '{print $3}'
```

and I could probably create a small script to kill a specific process but how would I create a loop that would check each ffmpeg process and kill it if its stale(runit will restart it afterwards)?

I think it would need to execute the command to get CPU usage twice with a minute cron and kill the process if CPU usage is the same. Would would I do this?

Comment: How can you determine it's stale? Low CPU usage? If so I'd indeed use cron for the job and grep for 'ffmpeg'. Then parse line per line and check if it's stale. If it is, grep the PID and kill. I'd be happy to whip up a script for that.

Comment: Sometimes its low, sometimes normal. In both cases, if you keep greping ps aux for that process, CPU usage is the same. I kill it manually, it just happens too often now and i'd be glad to have a cron to check and kill such processes.

Comment: Check my answer, the second one in particular. You can set a tolerance as you wish in awk, you can even supply it as an argument, if you please.

Comment: Can you please shed some light on what `awk '{ if ($3 > 0.1) { system("kill " $2); } }'` does to a stale process with CPU usage for 34.5 lets say?

Comment: Yes, it checks if the third column has a value lower than `0.1` (it's still higher in the code you supply but I changed it), if it does it gets killed. That is, if the value in the third column determines whether it's stale or not. - So with the updated code: a 34.5 would not get killed.

Comment: Try to define as precisely as possible, when you call a process stale. Which column makes you say, this is a stale process (which column and which value it ranges in).

Comment: So i know for a fact that lets say, stream 1 has died. I check it with the following command:
`ps aux | grep channel1` and get the following
`root      3909 34.4  2.6 1366232 216468 ?      Sl   12:00 231:29 fmpeg command here`
I wait few seconds and do `ps aux | grep channel1` again and get the identical reply with identical CPU usage of 34.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75042/discussion-between-shellfish-and-andy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so we do a couple `ps aux` requests and then we'll check for stale processes.

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup, change this if undesired
workdir="/tmp/.stale_process_killing"
[ -d "$workdir" ] || mkdir "$workdir"

# get ps aux outputs, change number of iterations if desired
for ((i=1; i<5; i++)); do
    # add file number to file
    echo $i > "${workdir}/psaux${i}"
    # add ps output to file
    ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg' >> "${workdir}/psaux${i}"
    # change this timeout to suit your needs
    sleep 1
done

# now parse the files using awk
awk '
    FNR==1 { ix = $1 }
    FNR!=1 { cpu[$2][ix] = $3 }
    END {
        for (pid in cpu) { 
            j=1;
            while (cpu[pid][j] == cpu[pid][j+1] && j <= ix) {
                if (cpu[pid][j++] == "") {
                    j=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j >= ix) {
                system("kill " pid);
            }
        }
    }' "${workdir}/psaux"*
```

Version containing debug prints, to safely check.

```
#!/bin/bash

# setup, change this if undesired
workdir="/tmp/.stale_process_killing"
[ -d "$workdir" ] || mkdir "$workdir"

# get ps aux outputs, change number of iterations if desired
for ((i=1; i<5; i++)); do
    # add file number to file
    echo $i > "${workdir}/psaux${i}"
    # add ps output to file
    ps aux | grep 'ffmpeg' >> "${workdir}/psaux${i}"
    # change this timeout to suit your needs
    sleep 1
done

# now parse the files using awk
awk '
    FNR==1 { ix = $1 }
    FNR!=1 { cpu[$2][ix] = $3 }
    END {
        for (pid in cpu) { 
            j=1;
            while (cpu[pid][j] == cpu[pid][j+1] && j <= ix) {
                print cpu[pid][j]
                if (cpu[pid][j++] == "") {
                    j=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j >= ix) {
                print "kill " pid;
            } else {
                print "no kill " pid;
            }
        }
    }' "${workdir}/psaux"*
```

Comment: kills valid processes too

Comment: Add the debug prints, see why it gets killed. I'll add another version with debug prints. - Debug version added, post output of malicious activity please.

Comment: Bummer! There are valid processes that have pretty constant CPU usage and change only occurs in 2-3 minutes interval...

Comment: Try to mess around with variables, more iterations larger time between checks etc. - the code pieces `i<5` and `sleep 1`, those are the ones you should tweak.